# MUI x-data-grid documentation example never works as expected

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I am implementing the exact same code shown in the material-ui library documentation here

https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/layout/#flex-layout

I am trying to implement the flex layout,

I just did the exact same steps and the console shows the error all the time:

Sandbox:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8ahs3n?file=src/App.js

[image]

Please help, appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation example you linked to there is one additional `div` wrapping what you have in your code: `<div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>`. Including that wrapper element (which gives the element an intrinsic height as mentioned in the console warning) gets rid of the console error. Here's a modified version of your stackblitz that does not have the error: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-m2uoq1?file=src%2FApp.js.

The 400px height in the documentation example can be replaced by whatever height you want -- it just can't be percent-based. If you want the `DataGrid` to be the full height of the browser, you can use `100vh` instead of `100%`.

Here's an example:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { useDemoData } from "@mui/x-data-grid-generator";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";

export default function FlexLayoutGrid() {
  const { data } = useDemoData({
    dataSet: "Commodity",
    rowLength: 50,
    maxColumns: 6
  });

  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <div style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100%" }}>
        <div style={{ display: "flex", height: "100%" }}>
          <div style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            <DataGrid {...data} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit full height DataGrid]

In my example I included the `CssBaseline` component in order to get rid of the default 8px margin on the `<body>` element -- otherwise using `100vh` will cause a scroll bar to appear; however the default margin (or a custom margin in your app) can be accounted for in other ways by using `calc` (e.g. `height: "calc(100vh - 16px)"`).

Comment: But I don't want the height to be 400, I want it to be the full height of the document?

Comment: @Normal I've added another example showing how to do it as full height and still get rid of the console error.

Answer (score -1):

Use a wrapper component such as Box from Material UI with flex display and height:

```
<div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
<Box  style={{
    display: "flex",
    height:400,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  }}
>
<Datagrid/>
</Box>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the benefit of having a static height of 400 and having the height defined on the flex item as well, that doesn't make any sense at all